# Register of table1 where not have in table2

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Table1
id

Table2
id_table1
```

I need the registers of table 1 where only **not** have registers in table 2.

Thanks

Comment: what is register? BTW : `NOT EXISTS( ...)` is your friend.

Comment: First two answers below are fine.  Also, you can run an internet search on `table 1 where only not in table 2`.  -1 the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard SQL

```
SELECT
    t1.registers   -- change to columsn needed from Table1
FROM
    Table1 T1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
         FROM Table2 T2
         WHERE T1.id = T2.id_table1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can to this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.id = Table2.id_table1
WHERE Table2.id_table1 IS NULL
```